# How to record the execution time of a function called by a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, time

I am creating an application (or program) that after the button is clicked creates a new window and displays the results of some maths in a listbox. I want it to also display the execution time of the math. I tried using `time.time()`, but apparently, I can't use that in a function.

I also tried using `timeit`, but I have no clue how to use it.

How else can I do this?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def do_math():
    window = Toplevel(root)

    listbox = Listbox(window)

    for i in range(1, 10):
        math = i ** 2
        listbox.insert(END, str(math))

    time = Label(window, text="The math took {} seconds to execute.")

    time.pack()
    listbox.pack()


b1 = Button(root, text="Click me!", command=do_math).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why do you think you can't use `time.time` in a function? Also, what part of `do_math` are you wanting to time? If you time the loop you're not just measuring the maths, but also the time it takes to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `time.time()` function because you had a variable named `time` inside your function which was causing some exception popping out (`UnboundLocalError`), renaming that variable to something else **OR** inserting `global time` ontop of the function would fix it in your case.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import time

root = Tk()


def do_math():
    # global time
    window = Toplevel(root)

    listbox = Listbox(window)

    start = time()
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        math = i ** 2
        listbox.insert(END, str(math))
    total = time() - start

    label = Label(window, text="The math took {} seconds to execute.".format(str(total)))

    label.pack()
    listbox.pack()


b1 = Button(root, text="Click me!", command=do_math).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Easier than I thought. Thanks!